# How to send room name in connect function in Django Channels

Tags: django, django-channels, django-channels-presence

I have several rooms in my programs. Each user can connect to these rooms and send messages. for each room, I have a group. I want to specify a room name for these group in connect function. but I don't know how to send room name in connect function.

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def chat_connect(message):       
   message.reply_channel.send({'accept': True})

@touch_presence
@channel_session_user
def chat_receive(message):
    data = json.loads(message['text'])
    myRoom = data['room']
    messageChat = data['messagechat']

    if not message.user.is_authenticated():        
        return

    Group(myRoom).add(message.reply_channel)
    Room_channels_presence.objects.add(myRoom,   message.reply_channel.name, message.user)
    message.channel_session['room'] = myRoom

    #store in db
    try:
        room = Room.objects.get(slug=myRoom)
        message_model = Message(
                            user = message.user,
                            room = room,
                            text = messageChat
                        )
        message_model.save()
    except:
        pass


    my_dict = {
        'user': message.user.username,
        'messagechat': messageChat
    }
    Group(myRoom).send({'text': json.dumps(my_dict)})
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to sending room's name. I used to onopen function in js file.
When we connect to a room for first time, in fact, we run onopen function for websocket.
we can send our text in body of onopen function. like this:

```
chatsock.onopen = function() {              
    //in order to set room' name
    var message = {
        messagechat: "",
        room: roomSlug
    }       
    chatsock.send(JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

then, we can receive this text in receive function on consumers.py :

```
def chat_receive(message):
    data = json.loads(message['text'])
    myRoom = data['room']
    messageChat = data['messagechat']

    if not message.user.is_authenticated():        
        return    

    Group(myRoom).add(message.reply_channel)
    Room_channels_presence.objects.add(myRoom, message.reply_channel.name, message.user)
    message.channel_session['room'] = myRoom

   #if seding message came from onopen function in realtime.js
   #we just want to create a session for room's name
   if not messageChat:
       print('notttttttttt')
       return
```